# How to organize(group) nodes under a closed element - XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping, muenchian-grouping

I have tried simple grouping XML with XSLT 1.0 and it worked, but here I have something more complicated and actually different situation.
So the XML structure is basically this:

```
<Main>
 <TB>
    --> some elements and stuff - not relevant
   <City>
     <Area>
       <Position>5</Position>
       <House>

       --> some elements and stuff

       </House>
     </Area>
     <Area>
       <Position>5</Position>
       <Block>

       --> some elements and stuff

       </Block>
     </Area>
     <Area>
       <Position>6</Position>
       <House>

       --> some elements and stuff

       </House>
     </Area>
     <Area>
       <Position>6</Position>
       <Block>

       --> some elements and stuff

       </Block>
     </Area>
   </City>
   <City>

   --> same structure but with several repetitions of Position 7 and 8.

   </City>
 </TB>
</Main>
```

What I need is to group the `Block`s and `House`s which are under the same position and remove the repetition of Position numbers. For example it will get like this:

```
   <City>
     <Area>
       <Position>5</Position>
       <House>

       --> some elements and stuff

       </House>
       <Block>

       --> some elements and stuff

       </Block>
     </Area>
     <Area>
       <Position>6</Position>
       <House>

       --> some elements and stuff

       </House>
       <Block>

       --> some elements and stuff

       </Block>
     </Area>
   </City>
   <City>

   --> same structure for Position 7 and 8.

   </City>
```

It's harder because the Position is not an attribute of the Area, so I basically have to identify the value of the Position of the Area, then grab the House and Block that fall under the same Position, and put them together surrounded by the same `<Area> </Area>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a fairly standard Muenchian grouping problem to me, grouping `Area` elements (not `House` or `Block` elements directly) by their `Position`.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:key name="areaByPosition" match="Area" use="Position" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- for the first Area in each Position -->
  <xsl:template match="Area[generate-id() =
                            generate-id(key('areaByPosition', Position)[1])]">
    <Area>
      <!-- copy in the Position element once only -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Position" />
      <!-- copy in all sub-elements except Position from all matching Areas -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="
            key('areaByPosition', Position)/*[not(self::Position)]" />
    </Area>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- ignore all other Area elements -->
  <xsl:template match="Area" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This assumes there are no other elements named `Area` elsewhere in the document, if any of the "some elements and stuff" may be named `Area` then you need to be a bit more specific, for example limiting the grouping to `Area` elements that are direct children of a `City`:

```
<xsl:key name="areaByPosition" match="City/Area" use="Position" />

<xsl:template match="City/Area[generate-id() =
                               generate-id(key('areaByPosition', Position)[1])]"
              priority="2">
  ...
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="City/Area" priority="1" />
```

(with explicit priorities because without that both templates would have the same [default priority](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#dt-default-priority) of 0.5)

Comment: This worked fine, until I actually found something that is not allowed. for example I have `<City A><Area><Position>5</Position>... bla bla<///>`
And then I have the same position 5 in `<City B>` it takes the elements under Position 5 from City B and arranges them under the elements of Position 5 in City A. 
And I want it to order the Houses and Blocks but stay in the same City.

Comment: @Syspect if you want to group `Area` elements by both `Position` and the containing `City` name you'll need to include the relevant stuff in the grouping key definition, something like `use="concat(../@name, '|', Position)"`, and the grouping predicate, like `key('areaByPosition', concat(../@name, '|', Position)[1]`